# The value of the output for my double variable is not correct on the Arduino Uno

Tags: c, arduino

I use this code to test if the output will be displayed correctly when I print double variable:

```
double t = (0.8*0.8*(10^5)*599*(10^-6)*1388.888889)/(287*(25+273)*14.7*3*(10^-3)*4);
Serial.println(t);
```

But my output on the serial port is 4.03 instead of 3.52

I am using Arduino UNO and Arduino C language.

What are the problems with my code?

Comment: are you aware that `^` is the bit-wise **xor** operator, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how could I solve this problem

In C,C++,JavaScript,Java:

Number 10^5 has to be represented in program as 1e5

and number 10^-6 as 1e-6

The use of '^' forces program to perform bit wise operation 10^5 = (10)^(5)

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3akey979.aspx

**Solution**

Change

```
double t = (0.8*0.8*(10^5)*599*(10^-6)*1388.888889)/(287*(25+273)*14.7*3*(10^-3)*4);
```

To:

```
double t = (0.8*0.8*(1e5)*599*(1e-6)*1388.888889)/(287*(25+273)*14.7*3*(1e-3)*4);
```

Now you get the correct result:

```
t = 3.5292104651726235
```

The int on arduino has very limited range: 32767 to -32768.
The long is 2147483647 to -2147483648

Avoid mixing int and double to avoid rounding error.

Use only double or you can use cast:

```
 double d = (double)(0.8*0.8*(1e5)*(double)599*(1e-6)*1388.888889)/(((double)287)*((double)(‌​25+273))*((14.7*((double)3)))*(1e-3)*(double)4);
```

Note on the Arduino

```
Serial.print(1.23456); //gives "1.23"
```

To get more numbers convert double variable to the string and print the string.

The example:

```
double num = (double)(0.8*0.8*(1e5)*(double)599*(1e-6)*1388.888889)/(((double)287)*((double)(25+273))*((14.7*((double)3)))*(1e-3)*(double)4);
char output[50];

snprintf(output, 50, "%f", num);

Serial.print(output); // should give you at least 3.529210
```

Comment: Which language do you use? In C I just checked: `double d = (0.8*0.8*(1e5)*599*(1e-6)*1388.888889)/(287*(25+273)*14.7*3*(1e-3)*4); printf("*Program End** %f\n",d);` and the value is: `3.529210`

Comment: I'm using arduino c language but when I tried your code in java it works but I want it on arduino for hardware purpose

Comment: @mamdouhabdelfatah When I used calculator (I used Spotlight on my Mac) it also gave me 3.529210

Comment: I know your code is correct but I think arduino c language has something different

Comment: @mamdouhabdelfatah I am not sure why you have so many numbers in your expression. Some of them are int type some of them double. From the numerical point of view they are not grouped in an optimal way. You can get so called "rounding error". My another suggesting is: if you can make all numbers same type - double.  For example double d = (0.8*0.8*(1e5)*599.0*(1e-6)*1388.888889)/(287.0*(25.0+273.0)*14.7*3.0*(1e-3)*4.0);

Comment: @mamdouhabdelfatah The int on arduino has very limited range: 32767 to -32768. The long is 2147483647 to -2147483648 Avoid mixing int and double. Use only double or you can use cast: `double d = (double)(0.8*0.8*(1e5)*(double)599*(1e-6)*1388.888889)/(((double)287)*((double)(25+273))*((14.7*((double)3)))*(1e-3)*(double)4);` Let me know if this works better.

Comment: yes now it works thank you very much , but there is only one question why the answer is 3.52 only why the rest of digits is not displayed if I want it 3.5292104651726235 what could I do ?

Comment: It is a feature of the `Serial.print` function! `Serial.print(78) gives "78"` and `Serial.print(1.23456) gives "1.23"`
See https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print. The solution is to convert double to the string and print string. You will get all the numbers!!!